# Creating next/prev pages bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, pager

I'm new to web designing and I need some help with creating 'next / previous' pages with bootstrap. My question is, do I have to create every single 'next' page so that I link the 'next' button to or I should just create one page?...Please help, I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use PHP for that and dynamic pages. You can create each page manualy and link it bat that is pain in the ass. You need to learn PHP after that you can create pagination for your data from database and display in your bootstrap page.